# Find the limit of the sequence $\{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

As in the title, I need help finding the limit of this sequence. $$\{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\}$$

I tried to multiply by the conjugate, but that just got me to $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$, and I'm not sure what else I can do. L'Hospital's rule doesn't get them out of their parentheses.

Comment: Are the braces the fractional part?

Comment: @RossMillikan: I thought that just indicated it was a sequence, where the $n$th element is given by the expression in the braces.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You want the limit as $n\to\infty$, right?

Answer (score 5):

Multiplying by the conjugate, as you did, is a good idea. This is because since $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{n} = \infty$, then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} = 0 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Comment: I think this is more like what OP was looking for; +1

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks for the comment & upvote. It wasn't $100$% clear to me either what the OP wanted, but I assumed they were only looking for the limit of when $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You could use binomial series:

$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1n}-1\right)=\sqrt n \left(\left(1+\frac1{2n}-\frac1{8n^2}+\cdots\right)-1\right)$$